# How to remove a document field using AngularFirestore?

Tags: firebase, angularfire2

According to the [Firestore docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#fields) one can do the following:

```
var cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('BJ');

// Remove the 'capital' field from the document
var removeCapital = cityRef.update({
    capital: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
});
```

However, using AngularFirestore, `FieldValue` is not available:

[image]

How can one remove a field using AngularFirestore?

**Edit:**

- Setting the field value to **null** does not remove the field
- Setting the field value to **undefined** is not allowed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the FieldValue.delete() method you have to import:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

or as camden_kid suggested:

```
import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't remove the field. I'll update the question to add that information.

Comment: Hmm, that’s strange. You can just make the import `import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';` to use the FieldValue.delete();

Comment: Thanks. The import works and `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()` does the job. If you update your answer I'll mark it as correct. I feel as though it should be doable through AngularFirestore though.

Comment: Actually, `import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';` works and is a neater solution.

Comment: Thanks, I just edited it. And yea I completely agree, angularfire2 is missing a few things like transactions as well. I eventually ended up switching to just using the Firebase Javascript SDK instead.

Comment: I used the Firebase Javascript SDK for my previous app without any hitches. If I run into more basic problems with AngularFirestore I may switch to it again.

Answer (score 1):

For Angular12 / Firebase 9 / AngularFire 7 imports should looks like:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

and then

```
fieldName : firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
```